# Drilldowns not carrying filters

Tags: drilldown, powerbi

When I use a drilldown on one of my charts, it doesnt carry the above value across in terms of Filtering. So lets says I have ABC, I click on A and it drills down to 123. If I click on 1, it wont filter other graphs on A1, it will just filter it on 1. Is anyone else having this issue, or do you have any fixes

Comment: Currently it is not possible. There is a related improvement idea posted [here](https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/10132329-incremental-drill-down)

Comment: Ah, thats a shame. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your data is modeled. If you ABC and 123 are columns in a single table, then it should work the way you're thinking it would.  If they're in different tables then it really depends how sophisticated you chose to make your model - for example, you might have a hidden composite key column in your 123 table that is used for relationships instead of the actual 123 column.  The composite key column could then enforce the full hierarchy you're looking to filter across.  If there's no good relationship between ABC and 123 (it's not a hierarchy you're willing to encode in the data model) then it's better to use a slicer.